# Folder Picker Unauthorized access for Sub Directories and files in them UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I am working on a UWP application. I use the `FolderPicker` to select a folder on the disk. Now what I want to do is search through the entire folder and pick video files and image files and show them in a slideshow.

Below is how I use the `FolderPicker` to select a single folder.

```
FolderPicker openPicker = new FolderPicker()
{
    ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail,
    SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.ComputerFolder
};
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

var SelectedFolder = await openPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
```

The problem I face is that event though I've picked the folder using the `FolderPicker` when I select a single file as `StorageFile` or a sub directory using a `GetFolderFromPath()` it throws an `UnAuthorizedAccessException`

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))'

Below is how I access both of them:

```
StorageFolder accessFolder = StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(SelectedFolder.Path + "\\subDir1\\subDir2").AsTask().GetAwaiter().GetResult(); // throws the exception

StorageFile file = accessFolder.GetFileAsync("DummyMediaFile.mp4").AsTask().GetAwaiter().GetResult(); // also throws the exception
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve your purpose:

### 1. Use `broadFileSystemAccess` capability.

Please refer to the end of [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) to add the `broadFileSystemAccess` capability to the `package.appxmanifest` file.

Looks like this:

```xml
<Package
  ...
  xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp uap5 rescap">
...
<Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" />
</Capabilities>
```

Then find your application in `Settings` -> `Application`, click and select `Advanced Settings`, open the `File system`.

After that your code can be executed smoothly.

### 2. Don't use paths to access folders

Although the path is a relatively simple way, in UWP, it is not allowed to directly access files or folders by path. You need to use the following method:

```cs
StorageFolder accessFolder = await (await SelectedFolder.GetFolderAsync("subDir1")).GetFolderAsync("subDir2");
StorageFile file = await accessFolder.GetFileAsync("DummyMediaFile.mp4");
```

> Note, please use this method when confirming the above file or folder name is valid, otherwise please use `CreateFolderAsync("name", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists)`

Comment: Hi, thank you for sharing a quick insight but I don't see a `broadFileSystemAccess` under the capabilities in `VS2019`

Comment: It is not an option displayed in the Capability list. You need to open the `package.appxmanifest` in Code mode (right-click the file and select `View Code`) and add it manually.